# org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder getLogOutput INFO: Driver logs no longer sent to console by default error using Selenium Java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, console.log, testng-eclipse

I'm executing a simple Selenium Java program:

```
package Testcases;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class First {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.setProperty("Webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\ashwi\\Downloads\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("url");
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

I am getting this error:

```
org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder getLogOutput
INFO: Driver logs no longer sent to console by default;
```

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

These log messages...

```
Jun 30, 2023 3:35:03 AM org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder getLogOutput
INFO: Driver logs no longer sent to console by default;
```

...aren't any indication of any *error* as such but *`INFO`* logs which states that the *`INFO`* logs are no more observed in the console by default.

To see the *`INFO`* logs back within the console you have configure the setting explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

you have to put the below line

```
ChromeDriverService service = new ChromeDriverService.Builder().withLogOutput(System.out).build();

webDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(service);
```

ref: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/browsers/chrome/#service

Answer (score -1):

3 points here:

1. Your error message is missing.
2. You didn't mention the url path.
3. You have mentioned driver.get("url"). You are calling url as a string when it should be passed as an argument. Like this: driver.get(url)

Answer (score -1):

I extract the zip file and change this line:

```
System.setProperty("Webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\Downloads\\chromedriver.exe");
```

hope it works

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Need to update the new browser version and save in this location